# Исключение e-mail оповещения о новых комментариях к некоторым постам в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток.

Активно гуглил, нагуглил такой хук https://wp-kama.ru/hook/notify_moderator
для исключения отправки модератору e-mail оповещения о новом отправленном комментарии для постов с ID номерами (12, 23, 31)

Сваял на основе его код, но что-то он не работает.

```
add_filter( 'notify_moderator', 'filter_function_name_9023', 10, 2 );
function filter_function_name_9023( $maybe_notify, $comment_ID ){

    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
    $ids_exclude_notification_posts = array(12, 23, 31);

   if ( in_array((int)$post, $ids_exclude_notification_posts))  {  
  return false;
   } else {   
  return $maybe_notify;
   } }
```

В чём ошибка, как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы не правильно получаете ID поста, потому что когда вы приводите к целому чилу обьект у вас будет **1** вместо ожидаемого ID поста. условие должно выглядеть вот так

```
if ( in_array( (int)$post->ID, $ids_exclude_notification_posts))  {  
    return false;
} else {   
    return $maybe_notify;
}
```

так же у вас разные имена переменной `$comment_ID`, получение комментария должно быть таким

`$comment = get_comment( $comment_ID);`

Comment: Видать, я ещё где то напутал. Внёс предложенные правки, а оповещения всё равно отправляются :(

Comment: кто автор коментария и поста? если это админ то стоит добавить этот метод еще на этот фильтр add_filter( 'notify_post_author', 'filter_function_name_9023', 10, 2 );

Comment: Понял, в чём дело comment_id и comment_ID по разному воспринимаются, от того и не работало.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь :-)